# adding dll path on Team city for nUnit runner

Tags: nunit, teamcity, runner

I tried a lot,but still not getting proper link and articles which can sort out my problem.

I have some NUnit test(s), which I want to integrate with TeamCity server; for this I am using the NUnit runner type in TeamCity. I gave my dll file path from which test has to execute but it failed to load my dll and gives the below error.

> **NUnit error running tests in 'C:\Labtronic Data\test\UtilityLibTesting.dll' assembly
>
> Loading assembly is compiled for v4.0.30319, MSIL
>
> NUnit runner runtime is v4.0.30319, x86
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'nunit.framework, Version=2.5.5.10112**

Do I need to do any additional configuration for this? Can anyone help me out in this.

Here I am attaching my NUnit build runner configuration also: [Team City config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66fRn.png).

Comment: can some one please help me out about my Team City Configuration ( see the attached document)

Comment: Looks to me like a mismatch between the version of NUnit that you're referencing in your unit test project (2.5.5 according to the error message) and the one that you're using to run the tests in TeamCity with (2.6.3 according to your config image). I'd suggest updating the version of NUnit in your project to 2.6.3